# Issue with string array

Tags: java, arrays, json

The below code gives result as test:`[someproduct, someproduct, someproduct, someproduct, someproduct]`. I am expecting result as `["someproduct", "someproduct", "someproduct", "someproduct", "someproduct"]` so that I will push the string array into json response

```
String[] Id = new String[5];
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    Id[i] ="someproduct";
}
System.out.println("test:"+Arrays.toString(Id));
writer.key("product").value(Arrays.toString(Id));
```

When I try access the jsonresponse like `response.product[0]`, i am getting first character '[' alone. I suppose to get first item(someproduct) of the array.

Please help me to resolve.

Comment: If `Arrays.toString(Id)` doesn't produce the output you desire, simply loop over the array and build that output yourself.

Comment: It's unclear what `writer` is, but does `writer.key("product").value(Id);` give the output you seek?

Comment: sorry, i am expecting  result as ["someproduct", "someproduct", "someproduct", "someproduct", "someproduct"] so that I can call res[0], res[1] etc. Can anyone help me write regular expression on this?

Comment: You expect that result when you print it out to screen? How do you print it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the problem is the method you are using is not sufficient.
one way of doing this, is to use another type of array (e.g. `ArrayList`) then `Override` its `toString` method.

here is an example:

```
 public static void main(String... args) throws Exception{
    ArrayList<String> array=new ArrayList<String>(){

        /**
         * 
         */
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

        @Override
        public String toString(){
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            sb.append("[");
            boolean isFirst=true;
            for(String s : this){
                if(!isFirst){
                    sb.append(",");
                }
                isFirst=false;
                sb.append("\""+s+"\"");
            }
            sb.append("]");
            return sb.toString();
        }
    };


    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
      array.add("someproduct");
    }
    System.out.println(array);


}
```

**output:**

```
["someproduct","someproduct","someproduct","someproduct","someproduct"]
```

NOTE:

There are many ways to make this code reusable, e.g.

1. creating a new class `ArrayListWithNicePrint` that `extends` `ArrayList`
2. creating a `static method` that returns you a fresh `ArrayList` with nice Print (I prefer this one really)

EDIT: (Based ON comment):

```
public class ArrayListWithNicePrint<E> extends ArrayList{


        @Override
        public String toString(){
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            sb.append("[");
            boolean isFirst=true;
            for(Object s : this){
                if(!isFirst){
                    sb.append(",");
                }
                isFirst=false;
                sb.append("\""+s.toString()+"\"");
            }
            sb.append("]");
            return sb.toString();
        }

    }
```

Testing:

```
public class Testing{
   public static void main(String... args){

   ArrayListWithNicePrint<String> list= new ArrayListWithNicePrint<String>();
   list.add("hi");
   list.add("hello");
   System.out.println(list);
   }
}
```

Comment: thanks, we can do it by overriding toString method !

Comment: As you ve suggested to create new class ArrayListWithNicePrint that extends ArrayList. can you please give me some example for the this.

Comment: thanks for your response Nafas. I have tried above the code, have added public static void main but it returns me "[someproduct, someproduct, someproduct, someproduct, someproduct]" without having double quotes. It seems toString() method is not called. Am I missing anything?

Comment: @ezhil I think you made a mistake on the initializations. I've added a test class and made the ArrayListWithNicePrint public to make it easier accessible.

Comment: thanks Nafas, it is working fine.there was some problem while initialization. once again thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
String[] Id = new String[5];

for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++) 
 {

   Id[i] =" **\"someproduct\"** ";

 }
```

hope it will work

Comment: Id[i] =" \"someproduct\" ";

Answer (score 1):

You can use some JSON converter library, or as a quickfix you could use something like this:

```
String[] Id = new String[5];
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    Id[i] ="\"someproduct\"";
}
String arrOutput = Arrays.toString(Id).replaceAll("\\[", "{").replaceAll("\\]", "}");
System.out.println("test:"+ arrOutput);
writer.key("product").value(arrOutput);
```

Depending on the content on your array elements more workaround would be needed. Maybe if you write more information we can help you better.

Answer (score 1):

why dont u try putting it into a List and then use Gson to convert the whole list into json format, dig a bit to get the correct format of json u want. for retrieving u can retrieve easily with the tag names associated with each element. What u require is not very clear so this is the best guess i can make

Answer (score 1):

Try with this code. it will resolve your issue.

```
    String[] Id = new String[5];
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            Id[i] ="\"someproduct\"";
        }
        System.out.println("test:"+Arrays.toString(Id).replace('[', '{').replace(']', '}'));
```

Comment: Is similar to my answer. OP wants that the elements are inside quotes `"`, as well.

Comment: Hi,  i am expecting result as ["someproduct", "someproduct", "someproduct", "someproduct", "someproduct"]. how do we write regular express for this? pls help

Answer (score 0):

When usin the JSONWriter object, you should use the built in array() and endArray() methods like this:

```
writer.key("product").array();
for (int i=0; i<5; i++) {
  writer.object();
  writer.key("name").value("someproductname" + i);
  writer.endObject();
}
writer.endArray();
```

http://www.json.org/javadoc/org/json/JSONWriter.html